# Having a UIBarButtonItems on top bar in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

This might be a small question, but how do you have a title bar with `UIBarButtonItems` in a view that is embedded in a `UITabBarController`?  For example, in the Apple Clock App, you see a title bar showing "Stopwatch" as the title for this tab.  In other tabs there are UIBarButtonItems up there as well.

[image: Image of Apple Clock App]

According to [this Apple GettingStarted Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/WritingaCustomClass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH18-SW1), the top controls are `UIBarButtonItems`, like on the World Clock page.  One puts it into edit mode, and the other opens a Modal dialog to select the location.  Neither of which are push segue navigations, which I thought were mainly what is used in UINavigationControllers

I know that I could embed the main view in a `UINavigationController` to give the Navigation Bar, but that seems like a lot of overhead for a bar.  I could add a UIToolbar up there, but according to [this Apple Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html) you should not do that:

> Note: For clarification, on iPhone, a toolbar should always appear at the bottom edge of a screen or view, but on iPad it can appear at the top edge.

For my app, I wanted a sharing button on the top right for at least one of the tabs, so it would load a modal Activity View Controller, so it is not strictly speaking a navigation (no push segue's like one normally does in a `UINavigationController`.  So while I CAN use a `UINavigationControlller`, it seems like unnecessary overhead for something that won't be navigating.

So, how is the best way to do add that bar for a title and UIBarButtonItems to a view controller embedded in a `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Apple's documentation says UIToolbars should always appear near the bottom, you technically *can* place them at the time and your app will still be accepted. Many apps do use a toolbar at the top of the screen.

### Best way

Use a UINavigationController.

It is not a lot of overhead and it has more advantages in the long run than a UIToolbar.

Advantages:

- You get a title placed on the top bar (UINavigationBar) for free. (No need to create a UIBarButtonItem or UILabel for that.)
- In the future, if you decide you do want a segue, you won't have to refactor and put a navigation controller in there. (Extensibility is a good coding practice to get in the habit of.)

tl;dr - Feel free to use a UIToolbar if you want something simple. Use a UINavigationController if you want to do it the "right" way and want to follow Apple's guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for the well written answer.  I very much liked how you addressed the use of UIToolbar (and that it would probably still be accepted), the reasons to use the UINavigationController, and even the tl;dr section.  This is definitely one of the best answers to one of my questions on Stack Overflow.  I will probably use the UINavigationController as you suggest for the reasons you provided.